# ActiveRecord select with predicate on childrens

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have such db structure:
term.rb:

```
class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :tasks, through: :students
 ...
 def accepted_tasks_count
    tasks.where(status: Task.statuses[:accepted]).count
 end
```

task.rb:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :notes, through: :submissions
 ...
 def notes_count
    self.notes.count
 end
```

I need to add some method which will return accepted tasks without notes.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes, through: :submissions

  scope :accepted, -> { where(status: self.statuses[:accepted]) }
  scope :without_notes, -> { includes(:notes).where(notes: { id: nil }) }

end
```

I've moved 'accepted tasks' query to the scope too, to make it reusable.

```
class Term < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, through: :students

  def accepted_tasks_count
    tasks.accepted.count
  end
end
```

To get all accepted tasks without notes, use this:

```
Task.accepted.without_notes
```

To get all accepted tasks without notes for the specific term, use that:

```
@term.tasks.accepted.without_notes
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved my life.